# Selecting rows of numpy array that contains all the given values

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a np.array:

```py
matrix = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', np.nan], ['C', np.nan, np.nan] ])
```

and I want to efficiently select all the rows that contains the given values

```py
samples = ['C', 'A']
```

but when I make:

```py
mask = np.isin(matrix, samples)
```

I get

```py
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

How can I efficiently get a mask when is True only in the rows that contains both values?

I focus on efficiently because its a sparse and big matrix.

thank you in advance estimates.

Comment: Did any of us answer your question?

Comment: @rayryeng I posted my solution my friend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally use:

```py
#Filter
test_elements = ['A', 'B']
mask = np.isin(matrix, test_elements)
vec_mask = np.isin(mask.sum(axis=1), [len(test_elements)])
ids = np.where(vec_mask)
existence = matrix[ids]
```

Thank you for you help guys.

Comment: `np.where` is superfluous. Use it to index into `matrix` directly.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be

```
[np.isin(samples, row).all() for row in matrix]
# [True, False, False]
```

*(But to be honest not able to tell anything about efficiency or performance...)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want something vectorized, I would suggest doing this comparison by transforming this into 3D and broadcasting over the third dimension.  Then for each slice, check each row to see if there is anything that is `True`.  Finally, if we see that for each row, every element is `True`, then this is the result we should return.

```
In [40]: matrix = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', np.nan], ['C', np.nan, np.nan] ])

In [41]: samples = ['C', 'A']

In [42]: samples = np.array(samples)

In [43]: mask = matrix[...,None] == samples[None,None]

In [44]: mask
Out[44]:
array([[[False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]]])

In [45]: mask = np.any(mask, axis=1)

In [46]: mask
Out[46]:
array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False]])

In [47]: mask = np.all(mask, axis=1)

In [48]: mask
Out[48]: array([ True, False, False])
```

To do this in more shortly:

```
# Define data
matrix = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', np.nan], ['C', np.nan, np.nan] ])
samples = ['C', 'A']

# Solution
mask = np.all(np.any(matrix[...,None] == np.array(samples)[None,None], axis=1), axis=1)
```

Take note that this will probably not do well with large sparse matrices....

Answer (score -1):

Here is pseudocode that might help you:

```
idxRows = []
for idx, i in enumerate(mask):
    if True in i:
        idxRows.append(idx)
```

This will give you the indices of all the rows that contain said samples.